# When there are two objects inside an array in Mongoose, how can i populate them?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-populate

```
router.get('/mypage/myreport-comment', catchAsync( async(req, res) => {
    const { id } = req.user;
    const { page } = req.query;

    const totalPost = await Comment.find({'reports.user': id}).populate('reports.user'); //.countDocuments({});

    let { startPage, endPage, hidePost, maxPost, totalPage, currentPage } = myPageCommentPaging(page, totalPost);
    const comments = await Comment.find({reports:{user:id}, isDeleted: false}).sort({ createdAt: -1 }).skip(hidePost).limit(maxPost).populate('author').populate('board');
    
res.render('users/myReportComment', {comments, startPage, endPage, totalPage, currentPage, maxPost})

}));
```

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const passportLocalMongoose = require('passport-local-mongoose');

const UserSchema = new Schema({
    nickname: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    role: {
        type: String,
        enum: ['user', 'master'],
        default: 'user'
    },
    createdAt: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    isWithdrawn: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
    }
});

UserSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose, {usernameField: 'email'});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;


const CommentSchema = new Schema({
    body: String,
    createdAt: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    author: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    },
    board: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Board'
    },
    likes: [
        {
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "User"
        }
    ],
    parentComment: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Comment"
    },
    hasReply: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
    },
    isDeleted: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
    },
    reports: [
        {
            user: {
                type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                ref: "User"
            },
            reportedAt: {
                type: Date,
                default: Date.now
            }
        }
    ]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Comment', CommentSchema);
```

I'm trying to find all Comment objects where a specific user is present in the reports field.

I want to populate the 'user' field in the 'reports' field, but the method `.populate( 'reports.user' )` is not working. What should I do?

I tried to output the code `const totalPost = await Comment.find({'reports.user': id}).populate('reports.user');` in various ways, but `totalPost` either outputs an empty array or is displayed in the format `reports: [[object]]`.

It might sound awkward because English is not my native language.

Comment: Can you post the code where you try to populate please, all of it, including your require/import?

Comment: Can you elaborate on "is not working" - does it throw an error?  clear the field? does it do nothing? crash the process?

Comment: Sorry, please edit the question and post the **full** code. I need to see if you are importing both models.

Comment: const totalPost = await Comment.find({'reports.user': id}).populate('reports.user');
Using this code results in an empty array.

Comment: I will upload the entire relevant code.

Comment: Just to be clear. `totalPost` finds the `Comment` but doesn't `populate`. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Depending on how I write 'find()', it either outputs an empty array or is displayed in the format 'reports: [[object]]'.

Comment: Hold on, an empty array means your `{'reports.user': id}` did not match. That's a different problem. Are you definitely getting a document for `Comment.find({'reports.user': id})`?

Comment: I just tested it, and `Comment.find({'reports.user': id})` also outputs an empty array.

Comment: OK. Do a `console.log('req.user=', req.user)` as the first line in your `router.get('/mypage/myreport-comment`. If its `undefined` then your query won't work.

Comment: I just tested it. The `console.log('req.user=', req.user)` is working correctly.
And `totalPost` is still an empty array.

Comment: When I used the `reports` field in the same format as the `likes` field, it worked. However, after changing it to the current format, it no longer works. I believe the key issue is how to `populate` the `user` field inside the `reports` field.

Comment: Try `const totalPost = await Comment.find({'reports.user': id}).populate({path: 'reports.user', model: 'User'}); console.log(totalPost[0].reports[0]);`

Comment: `totalPost` outputs an empty array. 
Therefore, `console.log(totalPost[0].reports[0]);` throws an error.

Comment: If `totalPost` is an empty array then there is definitely no match. Please post a document from your collection you think will match as I suspect there is a mismatch in how the document is structured.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I successfully received the value. Upon checking the database, I found that it stored data like this:

```
reports: [
      {
        _id: ObjectId("6530fc986bfs0ec1c28e48e7"),
        reportedAt: ISODate("2023-12-12T08:46:48.524Z")
      }
],
```

So, I entered the code as follows: `const totalPost = await Comment.find({'reports._id': id})` and I was able to retrieve the desired value. It's not completely resolved yet, but thanks to everyone for the help.

Comment: Glad you made progress. It would have been very helpful to include a sample document in the original question as it a common issue when there is a mismatch in query and document structure. Would have saved you a lot of time. Good luck with your project.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use

```
const totalPost = await Comment.find({
  'reports': {
    $elemMatch: {
      'user': id
    }
  }
});
```

Cause `$elemMatch` operator is useful for finding in array of object where there is at least one element in array.

For more info: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/

Then you can add populate method.

Comment: I tried it earlier, but it outputs an empty array.

Comment: is it working without adding population method?

Comment: I tried it without using the populate method, but it still outputs an empty array.